# Ref required to do bootstrap example on JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Ref [jsfiddle.net/le_beluet/1oc2wvrj/12/][1]
On this example the drop menu is not working.

I suspect the reference because it does work fine when I'm on local with donwloaded reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the issue:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown " href="# ">
```

Remove the extra space after dropdown for data-toggle. That should work. Probably some jsfiddle issue!

Same goes for al other attributes in your code. I have updated your code n now the modal works!     http://jsfiddle.net/1oc2wvrj/20/